# SSIS why all connection manager drivers pointing to 32 bit versions?

Tags: ssis, ssis-2012

I was struggling for long time to export data to Excel while running my package in 64-bit mode. Currently I have set Runtime64bit to false to get job done but I really want to run in 64-bit mode for some strong reasons.

For that I have installed [AccessDatabaseEngine_X64.exe](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CWz3T.png) (after uninstalling existing drivers). But I still get unable to acquire connection error. I have to run in 32 bit mode even after installing 64-bit driver. What is wrong?

What I have noticed is that when I creating a new Excel connection the connection manager dialog box is showing the drivers path pointing to 32 bit version. When I looked at other drivers, they are also pointing to 32-bit version. (see screenshot below). Is there anything to do with this?

[image]

My Environment:
 - Windows Server 2012 Standard (64-bit)
 - MSSS DT 2012
 - MS Excel 2010 (64-bit)
 - MicrosfotAccess Data Engine 2010 (64-bit)

My Excel file is saved in 97-2003 format (.xls)

Comment: Have you tried to use an .xlsx files?

Comment: Did any of the answers assist you Solow?

Comment: @alex yes. I did.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> But I still get unable to acquire connection error. I have to run in 32 bit mode even after installing 64-bit driver. What is wrong?

When you execute your package and look at the Progress tab, you will no doubt be getting an error message similar to:

> [Connection manager "Excel Connection Manager"] Error: The requested OLE DB provider Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0 is not registered. If the 64-bit driver is not installed, run the package in 32-bit mode. Error code: 0x00000000.
> An OLE DB record is available.  Source: "Microsoft OLE DB Service Components"  Hresult: 0x80040154  Description: "Class not registered".

When you set up your Excel Connection Manager, choosing Excel 97-2003 file type will default to the Microsoft Jet OLEDB driver which is available as a 32-bit version only.

Assuming you have the 64-bit [Microsoft Access Database Engine 2010 Redistributable](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=13255) still installed, what you need to do is click on the Excel Connection Manager you created in the Connection Managers tab. In the Properties pane, look for the ConnectionString property (under Misc if grouped by category).

You'll see the Provider is set as `Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0`, the 32-bit only driver. If you had chosen "Excel 2007" as the file type it would have used `Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0` which is 32-bit or 64-bit depending on which Microsoft Access Database Engine Redistributable you installed.

Change the `Provider` to `Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0` in the ConnectionString property. When you change this, you'll notice errors appear in the Error List pane similar to:

> Error 1   Validation error. Data Flow Task 1: Package: The requested OLE DB provider Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0 is not registered. If the 32-bit driver is not installed, run the package in 64-bit mode. Error code: 0x00000000.  An OLE DB record is available.  Source: "Microsoft OLE DB Service Components"  Hresult: 0x80040154  Description: "Class not registered".     Package.dtsx    0   0
>
> Error 2   Validation error. Data Flow Task 1: Package: The 'Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0' provider is not registered on the local machine. For more information, see http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=219816    Package.dtsx    0   0

These errors are related to SSDT and a point you made earlier which was:

> When I looked at other drivers, they are also pointing to 32-bit version. (see screenshot below). Is there anything to do with this?

SQL Server Data Tools is a 32-bit application and is likely the reason why in the "Add SSIS Connection Manager" dialog you are seeing the Connection Managers pointing to 32-bit versions. Requests for 64-bit SSDT have been made quite some time ago. It also the reason these new errors are appearing pre-execution and in a pop-up message box if you attempt to execute your package.

Notice the errors are *validation* errors which hints at the solution.

Select your Excel Connection Manager, set the DelayValidation property to False. This will stop pre-execution errors showing. Secondly, either for the Package or for the Control Flow task that uses your Excel Connection Manager, set the DelayValidation property to False. This allows you to run the package and stop the errors at runtime.

Comment: Sorry for the very late response. So you are saying, I can't have 64 bit ODBC drivers listed from designer because i am working on 32-bit version designer. Which is OK for me. To continue with other options, I am still unable to aquire connection after chaning connection string to Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0

Comment: Here the problem is. I have installed Office 64-bit which forces me to install 64-bit drivers only. I am getting error saying 32-bit drivers are not installed. Now i see a dead lock :(. BTW: I have made slight change in extended properties in connection string to "Extended Properties="Excel 12.0 XML;HDR=YES" which is correct IMO

Comment: I have set Runtime64bit = true to use the 64-bit drivers, but the problem is I still need to use 64bit bit oledb drivers for creating the DFT in the design time which looks like is not possible.

Comment: @SolowDeveloper Your connection string extended properties are correct.  Regarding your last comment, are you seeing validation errors when creating the DFT then?

Comment: Errors  using excell file saved as 2007 (xlsx) format. I will creat a new post withe the wel and sMple package attachments

Comment: You could convert this into a discussion on stackoverflow and we can go through it there rather than creating a new post.

Answer (score 1):

Let me quote this [FAQ - How to run SSIS Packages using 32-bit drivers on 64-bit machine](http://help.pragmaticworks.com/dtsxchange/scr/FAQ%20-%20How%20to%20run%20SSIS%20Packages%20using%2032bit%20drivers%20on%2064bit%20machine.htm)

> On 64 Operating System when you install Integration Services it will
>   install 32-Bit and 64-Bit version of DTExec commandline tool which is
>   used to execute SSIS packages.
>
> DTExec 32-Bit  can be found under  : C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft
>   SQL Server\90\DTS\Binn
>
> DTExec 64-Bit  can be found under  : C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL
>   Server\90\DTS\Binn   For more information click on the following URL
>
> http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms162810.aspx
>
> **If your SSIS package is referencing any 32-Bit DLL or 32-Bit drivers
>   from your package then you must use 32-Bit version of DTExec to
>   execute SSIS package.**

-- EDIT --

Extended explanation by example.

Imagine you create a new SSIS package. In it you connect to an Excel file. For this to work, you need to have MS Office, or the [Microsoft Access 2016 Runtime](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=50040)
 **in the machine that is executing the package.**

So, you are creating the package in VS in your desktop. You have Office 32 bit installed and it all works fine.

When you deploy to the serve, in this case a Windows 2012 (64 bit). You think that... STOP! The bit of the server does NOT matter. OK, but my SQL Server is 64 bit so... NO, it does not matter neither!

Once an SSIS package is published, look at the scheduled job properties. In there you can specify to run in 64 or 32 bit mode.

[image: Job step properties]

**Depending on this you need to have the correct version of drivers installed!**

Run the SSIS package on 64 bit; install 64 bit drivers!

Run it on 32 bit; then install the 32 bit drivers!

Comment: Hi Richardo. my question is about the problem while designing the package which is not recognizing or not looking for 64-bit drivers

Comment: when you create an SSIS package you would not care about this. If you use an OLEDB connection, the executing process (DTExec, or Visual Studio) is what causes the whole execution to be 32 or 64, affecting what driver is going to be used.

Comment: Now I understand that but error I am getting while creating dft is different.

Comment: I will post exact error but its siliar to error you mentioned in you answer where it days 64bit drivers not installed. Here its saying 32bit not installed

Comment: Hi Ricardo. I have Office 64-bit version installed. I appreciate your answer but this looks more relevant to another kind of problem which I am aware of but this particular question is more relevant to developing package in the design time.

Comment: @SolowDeveloper I dont think it is. Developing.. It does not matter! that shows 32 bit, because that is your desktop. The bitness at development time...Does not matter!

Comment: I suspect there is something to do with the registry I have messed up during the initial post cost I was trying all options and doing so much rnd and I remember I have used registry hack which works as 32-bit even though they are 64 bit drivers coz.

Answer (score 0):

Check if you have both versions of the DtsDebugHost.exe installed.

If you do you might need to install the latest service pack for Windows Server 2012.

[reference](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/dataaccesstechnologies/2014/05/21/ssis-packages-executed-from-visual-studio-business-intelligence-development-studio-bids-design-time-on-a-64bit-development-server-goes-to-unresponsive-state-during-package-execution/)

Comment: I have dtsdebughost.exe in C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\110\DTS\Binn